# vba: paring a values in an array according to conditions

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop

I didn´t find any post that could help with my problem that is why I decided to upload a post. I want to make a script that paring the value from one cathegory (H) with the nearest (but lower) value from other cathegory (C), without repetition. One cell value can be used only once. I´m beginer in vba. I am aware that I didn´t write a lot (and probably it isn´t correct), but if someone could help, I will be grateful.

```
Sub paringdata()

Dim lastrow, erow As Long
Dim i, j, chosedcell As Integer
Dim mydate As Integer
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet1.Range("B7").Select


For i = 2 To lastrow

chosedcell = Cells(i, 2).Value

    For j = 2 To lastrow
        
    If j < chosedcell And j > 300 Then
    erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)
    
    Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 2)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)

    End If
    
    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I see that you omit Option Explicit. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: It's not clear what results you are expecting.

Comment: I want that all value in the column "Enter T" that have name´s "H" in the column "Name" going to find the closest lower value in the column "Left T" wich name is "C" in the column "Name". No one cell could be repeated. The procedure starts with paring from the highest value to the lowest. E.g. the highest value in column "Enter T" is in C12. This cell is looking for the value in the column "Left T" and going to find D11. Then C8 is paring with D11 etc. IMPORTANT! The paring value from "Left T" coundn´t be higher then the value in the column "Enter T". Is it more clear what I expect?

Comment: Yes, I think so. You can do this with a formula.